# How do I include the views stylesheet after the application stylesheet in Rails?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I have a basic Rails site. I've only added a home page and my problem is that my `application.css` styles are overwriting my styles for the view -- `home.scss`.

Here's the tree of my application:

```
├── Gemfile
├── Gemfile.lock
├── README.rdoc
├── Rakefile
├── app
│   ├── assets
│   │   ├── images
│   │   ├── javascripts
│   │   │   ├── application.js
│   │   │   └── home.coffee
│   │   └── stylesheets
│   │       ├── application.css
│   │       └── home.scss
│   ├── controllers
│   │   ├── application_controller.rb
│   │   ├── concerns
│   │   └── home_controller.rb
│   ├── helpers
│   │   ├── application_helper.rb
│   │   └── home_helper.rb
│   ├── mailers
│   ├── models
│   │   └── concerns
│   └── views
│       ├── home
│       │   └── index.html
│       └── layouts
│           └── application.html.erb
├── bin
│   ├── bundle
│   ├── rails
│   ├── rake
│   ├── setup
│   └── spring
├── config
│   ├── application.rb
│   ├── boot.rb
│   ├── database.yml
│   ├── environment.rb
│   ├── environments
│   │   ├── development.rb
│   │   ├── production.rb
│   │   └── test.rb
│   ├── initializers
│   │   ├── assets.rb
│   │   ├── backtrace_silencers.rb
│   │   ├── cookies_serializer.rb
│   │   ├── filter_parameter_logging.rb
│   │   ├── inflections.rb
│   │   ├── mime_types.rb
│   │   ├── session_store.rb
│   │   └── wrap_parameters.rb
│   ├── locales
│   │   └── en.yml
│   ├── routes.rb
│   └── secrets.yml
├── config.ru
├── db
│   ├── development.sqlite3
│   └── seeds.rb
├── lib
│   ├── assets
│   └── tasks
├── log
│   └── development.log
├── public
│   ├── 404.html
│   ├── 422.html
│   ├── 500.html
│   ├── favicon.ico
│   └── robots.txt
├── test
│   ├── controllers
│   │   └── home_controller_test.rb
│   ├── fixtures
│   ├── helpers
│   ├── integration
│   ├── mailers
│   ├── models
│   └── test_helper.rb
├── tmp
│   ├── cache
│   │   └── assets
│   │       └── development
│   │           └── sprockets
│   │               └── v3.0
│   │                   ├── -_udyHoNbr8mDxcb1FD4zcd62fPT25x4FqWVBC60X7c.cache
│   │                   ├── 04DXMPUSoVP_-fLh-aopsGpiW0pCBI9QHWdeFHqvHzM.cache
│   │                   ├── 0Nvs4_B95Y8WLzaAlzbdZjs4V1_o4TV8i25ssJouVXc.cache
│   │                   ├── 0gaRI9teZBfqlCXBFb_ASmtcsghqc5SzvSBNI5eWYEc.cache
│   │                   ├── 0pmhe56I5c_nD54dC1NptrXWHo8lVYA8QL3sKPkaa7Q.cache
│   │                   ├── 0tQ55vokXY3Yxe03UTX-zYp0pEJs8A-bZsVHpj49-9E.cache
│   │                   ├── 150yZoF0L52XvUTDZcwf_hZMmIzZCCWq3EV9axcY2PI.cache
│   │                   ├── 19rFAZxwlyHLv8JjoDEVrwPbW1x2hNGkyXCmb3Kh9CI.cache
│   │                   ├── 1JrYC3pmcDEOE_30ORGR23zb9qfMxU0sa9d9PanNNL0.cache
│   │                   ├── 1gB_MaXnY7RsXzeCjiNIGXDDwThmKOlEnz_2QcVAKj0.cache
│   │                   ├── 1p7kKYPztxcYyEYm1MVoElGJnrvMDDjUZA0jNffzFCg.cache
│   │                   ├── 1rh3ivGd-OTZx8eTY5QRkZwwyxiovJfshnBOdsR0Lyc.cache
│   │                   ├── 1u-DtBlemUO8rNM6bYn_h-xEx1YsCvpt4GK0oiNdsYY.cache
│   │                   ├── 2AR8WP9xEJqRP0OP6CdH7t_dE71WyUF29Z29872pZNE.cache
│   │                   ├── 2DjQ5XcRyM6b4aePhw3tYSXJUG1BYUq1BrSCJ1IAQes.cache
│   │                   ├── 2SWA_WUUxTbtR9QyAThT2-zOu3KToXRm9OFWUUhVLvw.cache
│   │                   ├── 2Sq_IsrjPl1jIFsQOBfZMM8FAnHtdQN2h0CfK4RoqlI.cache
│   │                   ├── 2oPvhQ7rG7SWhyfwNuysMmOS95LHhY0a87mlOx7B6L8.cache
│   │                   ├── 3N7h_vp_XTiJqXxE5QmLBl4WWB1dOJBNnrDV-1fXJ_Q.cache
│   │                   ├── 3V6buWnLvclPDQz-TrCgm1xojuyYKUnMlt8SiyRNl08.cache
│   │                   ├── 3aZMT6P6apa2VU7OjmHLpuqqmcy9YxTFg_9kO35zUwI.cache
│   │                   ├── 3g0tFL9aruE-Ibr4NEEmMqvutnKdUJP_ARM7cWGgOPk.cache
│   │                   ├── 3gS1oVDI3ipI61tZXUdTc4m0BFJ17ETUVSjppXcEsKs.cache
│   │                   ├── 4cvn4VEhDs2re5sCOygiftuIA-cHoG15YGfkQBSu-lU.cache
│   │                   ├── 5AX8McfOryxCBBs5racOd1eZf2gCPpVQJbshmZGJf08.cache
│   │                   ├── 5Rn46sav1hloeeU4UPjJV-F2TAhxsw4iJg0cT0yZ_I0.cache
│   │                   ├── 5XanLuo4I5UbvX7lBb9PODlOv6PABd23xBdL80LyJ3U.cache
│   │                   ├── 5ZIrQwNuTGaLQCD8hZOmwT9GTPPnjSwY82MLy1vct78.cache
│   │                   ├── 6mCUy03g0mpEsMfbbN5kovmiYBRHc0rW26gZILvaf9s.cache
│   │                   ├── 76dIjI9rtTZJ2e3cpVNj7Vic52stKm32sYWCn75jS7w.cache
│   │                   ├── 7mOXP_D7l192wsU-ujdLi2xlApEWUhHHfPknIHej5k8.cache
│   │                   ├── 7o3TFrGZqM3_whc0E86fRpBffVKt99MIC5C6-jZKn3E.cache
│   │                   ├── 8WfjeO8ICMFK-m9ZCkmmx2KcKTom1Ow7YnDOKo5QQIc.cache
│   │                   ├── 8gSn1tCfESZ_LZQVcH7LPgwenc4Wp-IBBMlPMfDmXO0.cache
│   │                   ├── 9K01UXFYf1XOpIIx3C7oUrMhcehgh1090ojG8UgEjOQ.cache
│   │                   ├── 9VpisZISKXOhXMIsJpbwIgab3amCAuG5uB0vCB5T294.cache
│   │                   ├── 9lzZLLLVTgAJ9425RsXMW1Im_ACH6k7k7w-EphGLqTI.cache
│   │                   ├── 9spcX0DwuIW9Y1-KI2fcvGDJhGr4J6qtBAosJBzrn2U.cache
│   │                   ├── A1LcJiEVRggnDRMWO8D_z81p-7e9ANIIKgvmAXD9k38.cache
│   │                   ├── AG29BfyxHDk4z2NGx6HGA4i-IGKfyD4U3GXjF8LStDk.cache
│   │                   ├── AZnD2IPsgB_Pf-SUTcJiywtiCrstmO6sZdqZHXeVYtw.cache
│   │                   ├── BonhmiXi9qjJRhj6hRZLwIW4FnS5eXPmyzAoInoR75s.cache
│   │                   ├── Dj0VayUt2txbHH2N2I33yz6u1cYFVnz0h-ForkDWKR0.cache
│   │                   ├── Dn7kK6sUSw2iG47S9EXqrEvKXbQ_o02ofsqTLAUFAdQ.cache
│   │                   ├── DvsSyRUywDilD3j5VuE67sMYwx0TsND1SCZW6lK-8Ek.cache
│   │                   ├── Dx8rTP_oPMs5ke0QU6l_DP6ck5s6-zWEDuqSCKvqWdc.cache
│   │                   ├── EoqIdhhqcWo5i5NmozfIKI0O0UFmpZK1PjcTZtgnFYg.cache
│   │                   ├── FCd2iQvoL3NjyEHwaxIskiauq9kca3x9tjTDwFx-Jt0.cache
│   │                   ├── GZxy0obD6jOWu14ww3ne7X8osv-VfvJnKkoZwBOy_xY.cache
│   │                   ├── Gt55JrkVc8Mkv_7cE65IyfaOVcU0OspwdQqBhJTwJEs.cache
│   │                   ├── HJvXxSNlozf446s5a9CwANZ4qeSrzjJrGpTAHmhXrWk.cache
│   │                   ├── HtvGIOupq79SFo2ixg7zo2f5u32c7gM_EfPR5hETMPc.cache
│   │                   ├── HvsKtrcDjjqbLcsMMH479DrjB7HBDE6PCRZeeWoht7g.cache
│   │                   ├── I12wyVCMpnpfWWgi2zs8WvyhrX_rmCvXa4hcuCFl0XY.cache
│   │                   ├── Ip-MId2y1vmjxDswT_LvY2dsL6IBJPa76BD6nXXg28E.cache
│   │                   ├── IrNlOwzucXPikMV6hVNaXiXGVOuk6miAxbn1D5ooe8Q.cache
│   │                   ├── J6ZGigoXXJsY4ImsgCCUUbgVcBWt_Yy49Y2CIDLqGk8.cache
│   │                   ├── KbZIzDpGSOUomQduVAreP_dLI3T4BSMjBspviRDEHs4.cache
│   │                   ├── KjZOsp5820eds6qaKqvCPNfHyADGHC0E6CYGR_vDKl0.cache
│   │                   ├── L6yt7o96JcGePlklT3l7MbxFQaCB6MmchvGBszhP4Zg.cache
│   │                   ├── MK5fx0spHCaZHNrZzkxJGqY1xQlnYyfMwqKWusVchJ4.cache
│   │                   ├── MP8zBSwNbC9S5yIp4-2F-GMG8wFLKUGu4DqQTiajGm4.cache
│   │                   ├── Mb8rwQnIu3SRtuSwxG55BfVpvhgSijtY1ub8Bck8Z1Q.cache
│   │                   ├── MdTqZqNYZLtzuUAa4Q6PIkmPd2Hz_AN9HTtiO47cyuU.cache
│   │                   ├── Mo0C4EaQlpSeWnuDttmORm3qHxv1LV_SWuydeFX9d8s.cache
│   │                   ├── N15NT2hm7hfAshcQlvvecverYYcYwtSm0UAI7iByBwg.cache
│   │                   ├── NLz7T2jLcPsUgtI52b3qm9Iqo9qiVURh90iGoyuBecE.cache
│   │                   ├── NMiOCSXzCl_rGaJmUDlNCnVKq4Ge-WjbGMxI4kJsIa4.cache
│   │                   ├── NnIudy8FRrJFChSc-5Sid-8vROXNOmoSq3tG5R77xmY.cache
│   │                   ├── NoOkcw4kvDMPwBbku65vDYj1SVuaIXlvpPOK_olzLEU.cache
│   │                   ├── NyzSBEgaEmiqVj_KhmQr8vuRO4zJ5edUzOAmVLUn1ls.cache
│   │                   ├── OFWCT85P37nmzRGjCQlg20omxvq5rtNSygcC-Te044s.cache
│   │                   ├── OIgQJi-rJAcXaSTC2RkVemAcbGY5fXmkHxSDSv3hRdI.cache
│   │                   ├── Ofs28WsA2_acLoE-RHoRtdNYY9dsvC6G5iNTqhEAD-E.cache
│   │                   ├── OqMSFaa6VooNRei9ulDPE20Zg-nC0c4ph4Wbi3bmJdw.cache
│   │                   ├── PS_Clc-HQqQkIlWu5AgnefA3G_IpLYheQVJBazeDQyk.cache
│   │                   ├── Pagrk4QLyFE3tMOg4MTvrwzdv2pRKy3e_bSRAoSV8OY.cache
│   │                   ├── Pr4wMsjYSYoAcVxsfjLrOeIk-4QH2378JO3VvLp8Yo8.cache
│   │                   ├── QGQjvmnmnB0wE5JXNbfviRzvULNagwbpzx-w3Y-C-p4.cache
│   │                   ├── QJJp6EVkYTAXysmt5LGYNvXhYG6R7Qx4_g5doFKXz-Q.cache
│   │                   ├── R5GITpg85VB5uBNsf59jAzkMGaPjpZ7GCpTxC6OHjA8.cache
│   │                   ├── RjBnsjXfWLW_kPnVTIkvj12OYR_fhd1O57bNGUffjyM.cache
│   │                   ├── SJSj3aqQvy0VyfB-ccZ7TbloCQPOwd0uE-iG2ul2_j4.cache
│   │                   ├── SjIvRdbd7KfDegqRYSsXHlod7zr98Zmnh3ck0DDNpvM.cache
│   │                   ├── SkU8aELNbQiNJwCy0eZ1SUZdv7QrlAD9Ka0kGJQObuY.cache
│   │                   ├── TNfg_uF9f7zn78e0h_8k0AF6_C_goSKDZ71ZxgqFkGo.cache
│   │                   ├── TTADv5PuqGGj-iufWC5eE50zFFVxRIsBe2rgR2jyqRg.cache
│   │                   ├── T_ycBbgUxNcq-nPK5WO7Uhg9zh9MRpsdur8i6iNtCbU.cache
│   │                   ├── TtomkM4-Ty73NEEelYTzHLJgOgQfY5pXkL222Y5DrwQ.cache
│   │                   ├── Ut116MXVyhX8doXi_0_yPPNMEo19qYALR8BQMOSRPfg.cache
│   │                   ├── VoTfojdj5dJgpK4EfKz4kOV2VMOhF7prRcJAb_oxDkE.cache
│   │                   ├── VvFYQe3edI2mZEv1NFZDdGKow9oFA4acUIeFL096OXY.cache
│   │                   ├── Vwg27QGrdDZuU_omJoXYtJjXKtguOue4te04GFeqKF4.cache
│   │                   ├── W0I0xZRfLVqGA6J4uP7ZghGIKBf5a4MZ2XKul-V-yus.cache
│   │                   ├── WMqxalyJGZ-6zaCcQIL-6xf0b-slVbYX__P9dpzJuPk.cache
│   │                   ├── WPYYY65B5UNubW2Js4bGSqHxBpL7HI2Qqu71n40kljc.cache
│   │                   ├── WRwZEqIvvgP55eS3i3hXo5dA8b7J4KLv016dZtuq7xU.cache
│   │                   ├── WUBKA3DFfjuq3djuCltPHOkoQNU81Wajmeha3G7eEMI.cache
│   │                   ├── WdACZZ524TDAI9V7V8-bn3JgGDw3eIrm-9FmC1LEGJk.cache
│   │                   ├── Wn6AvoVoflcyGUkVk-NpqcVgtLmBmVJfmf8UrbDitUw.cache
│   │                   ├── XIO6eh3p8p4HG_RKAeGfoi3sVxHIFCTLED-QAOcYtcM.cache
│   │                   ├── XOCZ4KU-pgvpZdaUip7WQlFeNr1E2Hv2c52QED7CK4s.cache
│   │                   ├── YGwDbJqkARdZJ9OjEGS2nJTFnAtZDGlXBobD1-I4uxw.cache
│   │                   ├── YLGXUyiqB72YVqmkVjgfSYGb8UuMbGyfSVgFZQ4SSWY.cache
│   │                   ├── YgWnr0MLBzSJ_3gShOEzjC8SyFQ6zcQLH93nhZuNK-0.cache
│   │                   ├── YzOKPAilvfyhcvU-rmHmEGxO2rholinYmtpN70Zzsv8.cache
│   │                   ├── ZY4mQKFOFnhX0opDTGy4Vgk_yr4sn4WBVHobl9L0Ze4.cache
│   │                   ├── ZySWNowH5DhxnwO0IUBFH9aVNIIyDiJGpXbeoLfeQ-8.cache
│   │                   ├── _0q9Uo6Bx5rzHDMMfZGb5DV0UC8JmV7tnqfnjyI15HI.cache
│   │                   ├── __2_GuJsqAlIZAQ-mvlSLi6IvO09MEV3s8KX3M4a6ps.cache
│   │                   ├── a4yVK44RdAMRZaVJkayEg9xS3FE8zlzqJ1xWz7N2JIc.cache
│   │                   ├── aUxvLnXTJ_y49YV2wM4LAHRNDTE3Bq7yLuYxUmJFSxA.cache
│   │                   ├── bjYysLKZ1XQdrnVmgHhi6fR8XuQiybfV2uxSe9I94TU.cache
│   │                   ├── c6nsnkpYbkobY6W8wpjnt2Z7V_MAlHKdH21P7aOsnnA.cache
│   │                   ├── d2SYYgfSQsPIKVKaHcAKS_9RC3srBaEHSPpudK5y5kM.cache
│   │                   ├── eppuzzfQWfNzlJxuekG27w8DR7HMxAf5GGS6SI5Bqe4.cache
│   │                   ├── ez3ZTm9G-9uHcR3v9sXaA_a4EPeWgioekdlkc2tFHL0.cache
│   │                   ├── fjq0hBnLzyQIbL13x8Rq0lqtgrwnp3vR-c0DDk07_HA.cache
│   │                   ├── fkP1BMWXbyCduzm30RULgdBrR7Kagui88UxrRnRwpK0.cache
│   │                   ├── g7g7oOaZisdjbdllxaVrD_thgc3n1JymlJvMR1gcBwU.cache
│   │                   ├── hWgBi-XJJmccL44zdBKmy8G4TXIVeeuPA1JE7UNXn3w.cache
│   │                   ├── hWncJ74B83PjTsbJo3fswrgYKoXqVaAmswQb3XP-AFA.cache
│   │                   ├── hayrmSWnmKfTFFruN7IGtXn7Z5iOWr9SdfyeSdcB4OY.cache
│   │                   ├── hlF_zCpDYLy8C7bRDdi15XLviJc3De3KhI8qGzofcdE.cache
│   │                   ├── i1ujYmSMPg-_D_dH0Rnlt40Szk6ztxLKbojbePO7Qp0.cache
│   │                   ├── iESAAIu8UuiYndT7neiTvUOuGcZKm9WUnyYRCSebKIE.cache
│   │                   ├── inDeLxcrn-EBnLR7GaBrSQW4JZy0HpiFvABD1Rj_O38.cache
│   │                   ├── iqmVafC2rdsAQSHuV7WTjQZgU8VLAKCpSggmcXGrCy8.cache
│   │                   ├── j2qifjnHWw_dsiORZ2TynZotbSrX10kVddDLLBmgQCc.cache
│   │                   ├── jHq1r6wm9dB4cfLGb9XLAkI7dfAbb7V05eaa1HkoiWs.cache
│   │                   ├── jQfNlGNh_WJdzbfacLGG-8GZShjZTORuy6c9hBfmXUw.cache
│   │                   ├── jVk6mOPxQ8Z8iheCF7YJ6dFeaqR-8Hncsilnx-hKdVk.cache
│   │                   ├── jdle5lr2-eGKcTF-sln7sWGa3Izymes3t18NkNrwBLQ.cache
│   │                   ├── jeTDKEjFZF7vu7BBAzgxdgViha90vlDx9wzqPl8bjGI.cache
│   │                   ├── jfKtpecquYm_egh4M2bmbxFVzmkqkq8vRzC4SyIksdI.cache
│   │                   ├── jpww174e1KqwpBK1GCn427EswO5DSM1mfcj_YIwItEM.cache
│   │                   ├── k3w9AnmHslJsdb8JqDKvDqGwwWWXVXmi0lnLXdQ0M9k.cache
│   │                   ├── k82E0QLsnXDbwakca68gl3H8CNGq4wekTECLb_DMSz8.cache
│   │                   ├── k8S4AT67peMGIVQRrkdbQdhMlIYchm9BQTiFtvpDPJk.cache
│   │                   ├── kfd0zLo35feSA51R1f2RlFADzNvBhRYNjQuoqRXZsGA.cache
│   │                   ├── kqsyboe0zAe5j3JbnfkwbdKkGdtWk7LBtrjmwbQSG1Y.cache
│   │                   ├── l0yNava7AfwZ2w3wsQXxZk1QxNzzsP862I_deNOhMJs.cache
│   │                   ├── lX9_oUYApZV-OwQgkcuo-rae9J975_pGYIvlAiNoxwc.cache
│   │                   ├── lun_G2QYwtzIQ3TsKhcyNfiqrQKug4i9rRCjqnFKD1g.cache
│   │                   ├── m4jw89UKaX62yImplg0xQ2LJ3XXMNAkKqkKoo6lCVVY.cache
│   │                   ├── mFHPd9EeTsEvAT01yajJs07KNTHW5Cx-IMPNBvLkRlY.cache
│   │                   ├── mKQKN_P_8jYD-Q80hhjvo4e3LImaXAMIThYLqa9Apvw.cache
│   │                   ├── nKYFuE1u6tsnHRqT53kjEw5hhrvT6ZQI0kvIXOqGNbU.cache
│   │                   ├── nUPZpqydB9sOr9g-fXPlpK365zIEBUPmd7BwIa142fQ.cache
│   │                   ├── npskyJqPbYF4XR6qCTUzAXY9fpaHfepqy-XjoX4P4cg.cache
│   │                   ├── oNbHHK3U4citHUZIpFGmI1JBRRJ3Qt7s_iTAkwT-ceg.cache
│   │                   ├── oV1Vk-_aSjjXcRonoc3QIidwZtMLEwnsFNoFT22a77E.cache
│   │                   ├── oWqD5Ril2X0leLmgQPJBuhEOSWwrTMpGRXaiQaVrSdE.cache
│   │                   ├── pWbNVsKd3l-Fc13aY_6dfOO8RCWeJEuTr0PDdsYKROE.cache
│   │                   ├── pbbMCtJbq4nfjKNWAJvLBfVOFnH-DVkTh9gAlxHFqnM.cache
│   │                   ├── pmnpnEm0pvacyLk59QBudtKD2kiCxSflrF9_30qplB4.cache
│   │                   ├── puDNZEVH2IG1D9yWBCqDdl6vKABpjKO8fyGvHn97vns.cache
│   │                   ├── pyctbGIot62EehZ8fwloLeWjBcPTTM9EZw2WQ-9thkg.cache
│   │                   ├── q-VhsGGuZ4HsOdNy6DqjjiJKmgy2qT8zwONZ-5eaNg8.cache
│   │                   ├── qdo5G7mCwLqDyu1u54zet3xBwhz3SycuhAUx_CiA0aA.cache
│   │                   ├── qq1MStRxuuIYvU9tUZlw2wrjZ1DnUJJjRfbuHCOOuYg.cache
│   │                   ├── qvJu15rp-N4oCxzel97CJFPs0ASRrx7ohEN5rTtGRqc.cache
│   │                   ├── rfw8HrFw9hfM3KN1ytWiT-xV5eFo9qOXjaPz7F-KnXY.cache
│   │                   ├── s25ZzfYwY2NMoyIgydDEQQr3D8xQdP89gvD7fiJHwEc.cache
│   │                   ├── s359NqbMRGwN2PmCOjNXH1f-6ePoEA56LW8t5naT7VY.cache
│   │                   ├── sFJ3hZQZTMoQYXV6EjljgDJ23G2UCj6clXFHrBN2ISg.cache
│   │                   ├── s_zlgJcia6omZaqOwM_nNYgwAQVObueMzTp_Kyq_ifI.cache
│   │                   ├── tq6pyU_5tJQG5sW61yYTVuJBxpTOcIAiWnH-TjEudik.cache
│   │                   ├── u0N4ae2Vv6RPaOB8o7JekatvXqQjZ-3PDbETIFYz0gE.cache
│   │                   ├── uiPFsA6SoxbBFeXGO-fRlvX3LXmlNlglnAwVN06FnaM.cache
│   │                   ├── ulwdRAIeXUMzYvuLAkhrBOpAsSwkvKPx-mOM_kZbits.cache
│   │                   ├── urQSdnFo9vp_YRTTxwn455E1K5z2ZFWipD64-7kTq_w.cache
│   │                   ├── vfVVpdfOLH8iyJW4fozE0L8PaWvTfNFhMzTEBiLxQh8.cache
│   │                   ├── vsaV25CTZdK8IjSQdpH0imFqDYclBIWP0mZvq65NnHc.cache
│   │                   ├── w4-bqDviy2tDngXgflmgq6JQ_9FM-AmWLIG_623oTpw.cache
│   │                   ├── w8KuIwM9F_0a0LHM3xGSHs9z8FZwj5UYTVB0nZBUgEU.cache
│   │                   ├── wDmPq1P99PN5k2PLZgbCLCOl2XG8KPa3JvzmLLw0s7E.cache
│   │                   ├── weg74ABpuXSih6gGK-bK_PxPo0ign2xyyAmbPeHOir8.cache
│   │                   ├── x1luA6hWQw3GsIbvxqqk4-lfnVgoa8LNrmFXP72UdEM.cache
│   │                   ├── xZZwR_zsIqEVB8Sw-FXovLCiNhvThbxY0ENkVwsIewE.cache
│   │                   ├── xqycfES3uRm__XhaFSv3BsS2wH-QjF_207rDuJSWVdI.cache
│   │                   ├── ykHjasv52EA2lDAitxeGbspyadnEobn24yzl-KkiK_0.cache
│   │                   ├── z3DwRSEow7HMHBKLiPeep5f98n8spHTamZkIOktzIJk.cache
│   │                   └── zHmIZg8dWbdm0gYSf5HKcDO5_iBLzet2Kt6q_ai05z4.cache
│   ├── pids
│   │   └── server.pid
│   ├── sessions
│   └── sockets
└── vendor
    └── assets
        ├── javascripts
        └── stylesheets
```

How would I go about including the link to my `home.scss` stylesheet come after my `application.css` stylesheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways of doing this.

If you're specifying files in your application.css file, the bottom ones will have precedence (so put `*= require home` BELOW whatever is overwriting it.

If you want to specify the file outside of the application.css file, you could pass it from your view into your layout like so:

**Layout**

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all'%>
<%= yield :page_specific_css %>
```

**View**

```
<% content_for :page_specific_css do %>
   <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'specific/profile'=> true %>
<% end %>
```

...and then make sure that the page-specific file is being precompiled. This will always load the page specific css file after application.css.

I find the easiest way to manage styles, though, is to simply turn application.css into an .scss file, and specify imports there. It allows for the sharing of mixins, and can help you explicitly state what is included. For instance, on my current project, it looks like this:

```
/* CHARSET
-------------------------------------------------- */
@charset "utf-8";


/* IMPORTS - LIBRARIES - BOOTSTRAP
-------------------------------------------------- */
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";


/* IMPORTS - LIBRARIES - JQUERY UI
-------------------------------------------------- */
@import "jquery.ui.core";
@import "jquery.ui.theme";
@import "jquery.ui.datepicker";


/* IMPORTS - SCSS MIXINS
-------------------------------------------------- */
@import "mixins/*";


/* IMPORTS - LAYOUT CSS
-------------------------------------------------- */
@import "layout";


/* IMPORTS - CONTROLLERS' CSS
-------------------------------------------------- */
@import "controllers/*";
```

The one scenario for which I've failed to account is if you're requiring the tree. In this case I don't know for sure, but I don't believe you can specifiy priority there.

Answer (score 1):

Try whith this change to the application.css

```
 ...
 *= require home
 *= require_self
 ...
```

And delete line with `*= require .`